# Growth rate of a function

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods

I am having some trouble determining the growth rate of the function $m(n)=\inf\{m: \frac{1}{2^m}\le \frac{1}{n} m^{3/2}\}$. This comes up in problem 2.2.8 in Durrett's probability book. Essentially, I'm having some very rough heuristics (and probably incorrect) that says $m(n)$ grows like $\log_2(n)$. If I can prove (or see) this, I can solve the problem in the book. A general method would be desirable since I'm interested learning the techniques. However, any insight would be helpful!

Comment: Set $n=2^m m^{3/2}=2^{m+\frac{3}{2}\log_2m}$. Solving for $m$ gives:$m+\frac{3}{2}\log_2m=\log_2 n$. Now, the $\log m$ term is dominated by the linear term $m$, for large values of $n$, thus can be neglected. Hence as you said, the growth rate is $\log_2 n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$m(n)
=\inf\{m: \frac{1}{2^m}\le \frac{1}{n} m^{3/2}\}
$

If
$\frac{1}{2^m}
\le \frac{1}{n} m^{3/2}
$,
taking the reciprocal gives us
$2^m
\ge n/ m^{3/2}
$,
and
taking logs gives
$m \log 2
\ge \log n-\frac32 \log m
$
or
$m \log 2+\frac32 \log m
\ge \log n
$.

So we want to see
what this tells us
about $m$
in terms of $n$.

If
$m \ge \dfrac{\log n}{\log 2}
=\log_2 n
$,
this is certainly true.
Therefore
$m(n)
\le \log_2 n
$.

Suppose $m$
is slightly less than
$\log_2 n$,
say
$m = \log_2 n -c$
where $c > 0$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
m \log 2+\frac32 \log m
&=(\log_2 n -c) \log 2+\frac32 \log (\log_2 n -c)\\
&=\log n -c\log 2+\frac32 \log (\log_2 n -c)\\
&=\log n -c\log 2+\frac32 \log (\log_2 n -c)\\
\end{array}
$

and this will be
$> \log n$
for large enough $n$
for any $c$.
So we have to find a smaller $m$.

Suppose
$m = (1-c)\log_2 n $
where $c > 0$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
m \log 2+\frac32 \log m
&=(1-c)\log_2 n  \log 2+\frac32 \log ((1-c)\log_2 n )\\
&=(1-c)\log n+\frac32 (\log(1-c)+\log (\log_2 n))\\
&=\log n+\frac32 \log(1-c)-c\log_2 n+\frac32\log (\log_2 n))\\
&< \log n
\qquad\text{for large enough }n\\
\end{array}
$

since
$\dfrac{\log \log n}{\log n}
\to 0
$
as
$n \to \infty
$.

Therefore
$m(n) > (1-c)\log_2 n
$
for any $c>0$
for large enough $n$
(i.e., $n > n(c)$).

The next step,
which I will not do,
would be to find a $f(n)$
such that
$m = \log_2 n -f(n)$
satisfies
$m \log 2+\frac32 \log m
< \log n
$
and
$\dfrac{f(n)}{\log n}
\to 0
$.

Based on the
$\log\log n$
term,
I would guess that
$f(n) = a \log\log n$
would do
for a large enough $a$.
The algebra would be
trickier,
so I will leave it this,
having showed that
$1-c
\lt \dfrac{m(n)}{\log_2 n}
\le 1
$
for any
$c > 0$.

Comment: If my calculation is correct, $f(n) = \frac{3}{2}\log_2(n)\log_2(n)$ would work fine. Thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Your heuristics are in fact correct.  One heuristic is to isolate the main term involving the unknown variable, which in this case is $2^m$.  Solving, we get $2^m \ge \frac{n}{m^{3/2}}$.

To solve for $m$, we take logarithms, which gives $m \ge \log_2 n - \frac32 \log_2 m$.  Since $\log_2 m$ is insignificant compared to $m$, we can ignore the $\log_2 m$ term, which shows $m \sim \log_2 n$, as you suspected.

For more accuracy, we can then feed this approximation into the $\log_2 m$ term we earlier ignored, finding $m \gtrapprox \log_2 n - \frac32 \log_2 \log_2 n$.

More formally, because $\log_2 n$ was only an approximation of $m$, we would incur a slight error when plugging that into $\log_2 m$.  We should instead substitute $m = (1 - o(1)) \log_2 n$ (it is easy to see we overestimate $m$ before), which gives $m \ge \log_2 n - \frac32 \log_2 \left( (1 - o(1)) \log_2 n \right) = \log_2 n - \frac32 \log_2 (1 - o(1)) - \frac32 \log_2 \log_2 n = \log_2 n - \frac32 \log_2 \log_2 n + o(1)$.

Once you have this estimate, you can always substitute it back into the original inequality to confirm its accuracy.